# Need PowerShell function to pick up existing folder which is changing on server reboots

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have one requirement in PowerShell that whenever server restarts we get new folder like "50d6f41f80668b6e3bd635dd78175527" in specific location, the same file we use in below piece of code . But below is the hardcoded code hence we need dynamic code whenever new folder gets created and  that file should be picked by below code while running PowerShell script. could you please guide me in this.

FYI.. Always we have one folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Syslogd\DBCache\` location

```
$oldestFile = $(Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Syslogd\DBCache\50d6f41f80668b6e3bd635dd78175527" -filter "*.bin" |
    where-object {$_.CreationTime -lt $limit} |
        Sort CreationTime |
        Select -First 1)
```

Regards
LKD

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$oldestFile = $(Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Syslogd\DBCache" | Get-ChildItem -filter "*.bin" |
where-object {$_.CreationTime -lt $limit} |
    Sort CreationTime |
    Select -First 1)
```

Comment: Sorry, had to edit a couple of times for proper formatting...